# Conditionally changing a variable data type based on input

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

We have a stored procedure that gets call from an application.  One of the input to the SP is SSN. We are using SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise Edition.

The SSN data type is input as `VARCHAR(9)`.  We take that SSN and join it to a table who has the SSN stored as `DECIMAL(9,0)`.  This causes an implicit conversion at execution time and is affecting performance.

My original plan was to have the input come in as `VARCHAR` and just copy the variable over to another variable with the `DECIMAL` datatype however, we have a kink in the process. A user can also input text as 'new' when there is a new client.  When this happens, we get a failed to convert datatype varchar to decimal.

Is there a way to conditionally change the data type of a variable based on the input it receives?

Here's an example of what I am trying to use now, to no avail, as the instances where 'new' is entered cause a conversion error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedureFromApplication](
    @SubscriberSSN VARCHAR(9))
AS
DECLARE @SSN_DEC DECIMAL(9,0)
SET @SSN_DEC = @SubscriberSSN
```

Any ideas on how to have the datatype able to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should store SSNs as strings and not numbers, because they can start with 0.

I think the best you can do is to have the resulting value be `NULL`

```
SET @SSN_DEC = (case when isnumeric(@SubscriberSSN) = 1
                     then cast(@SubscriberSSN as decimal(9, 0))
                end);
```

Comment: Absolutely agree, unfortunately, as it usually goes, this was put into place long before I took my position as DBA here and I have to work around how the application already functions.